# Download Glassfish server 3.1.2.15

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I want to download Glassfish server version 3.1.2.15.

I have searched glassfish 3.1.2.15 in the web but could not find a link to download. If anyone can put a link to download glassfish 3.1.2.15. version it will be very helpful.

I look out in the below link but doesn't find glassfish server version 3.1.2.15

[Glassfish Server 3.1 Nightly download](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/v3.1/nightly/index.html)

[Glassfish Server 3.1 Promoted download](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/v3.1/promoted/index.html)

[Glassfish Server 3.1 Release download](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/v3.1/release/index.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Where can I find/download X?" is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: ok.fine.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest 3.1.2.x that you will be able to find is 3.1.2.2 which is the last open source edition of GlassFish 3.1.2. More recent versions are only available for **Oracle** GlassFish, which is not free to download, so you will need an Oracle support account to get hold of it.